# How to hide mouse cursor in Qt Application?

Tags: qt, modal-dialog, cursor, hide

`qApp->setOverrideCursor()` method works successfully, if I want to hide mouse cursor, except one condition. If I add a dialog that is modal, and while it is shown, if the cursor is out of dialog's borders, it is shown again. Have you got any idea about the problem?

It does not matter how the solution for hiding mouse cursor is; whether by Qt or at the operating system level. My operating system is Windows 7.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a trivial MCVE which shows the problem. Just *main.cpp*, which creates... I don't know, an empty main window and then opens a dialog?

Comment: I just created a mainwindow and added a qpushbutton. when button is clicked, modal dialog is shown. thats all. if dialog is not modal, mouse is hidded as expected. By the way, I have resolved the problem. the solution is to include "winuser.h" from windows api and call ShowCursor(false) method thats it.

Comment: Great. You could write that solution as an answer, and then mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot hide the mouse cursor when it leaves your window (or dialog-window), because it is then handled by the window-manager of your OS. A workaround would be to constrain the mouse to your window/dialog, so it cannot leave. You will either need to look through the MSDN to find the specific windows functions to do it, or do it like in kshegunov's code example on the Qt-forums: https://forum.qt.io/topic/61832/restrict-mouse-cursor-movement/12